how to create CSRF Token in .net8
I tried to send a file to server. Although Posting json was pretty simple, I faced lots of troubles for sending excel file through API (Uploading xlsx file to server).
Server side code
    app.MapPost("/uploadexlsx", async (IFormFile file) =>
    {
    List<string> validextensions = new List<string>() { ".xlsx" };
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    if (!validextensions.Contains(extension))
    {
        return $"Extention is not valid({string.Join(",", validextensions)})";
    }
    string filename = "File1" + extension;
    string path = @"D:/";
    try
    {
        using FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, filename), FileMode.Create);
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        return filename;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception or return an appropriate error response
        return $"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}";
    }
    });

Client Side:
    public async Task SendExcelFileToServer(string filepath , string filename , string   InnerAddress)
    {
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set the request URI
            string requestUri = ServerAddressTextBox.Text.Trim() + InnerAddress;

            // Create multipart form data content
            using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                // Add file part
                using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
                {
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType =   
                       MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.openxmlformats-
                          officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    form.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);
                }

                // Send post request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form);

                // Check response
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Try sending data again and check your connection!");
    }
    }

According to response of api to postman's Postrequest:

"
`System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint HTTP: POST /upload2 contains anti-forgery metadata, but  a middleware was not found that supports anti-forgery.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAntiforgery() in the application startup code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseAntiforgery() must go between them. Calls to app.UseAntiforgery() must be placed after calls to app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization().
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingAntiforgeryMiddlewareException(Endpoint endpoint)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
Accept: */*
Host: 26f2-51-81-84-47.ngrok-free.app
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.38.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------085075967638336328741999
Content-Length: 11245
Postman-Token: da76f52f-4c8d-4430-8834-b4ed5fb65ef9
X-Forwarded-For: 51.81.84.47
X-Forwarded-Host: 26f2-51-81-84-47.ngrok-free.app
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
`
"

it seems like I have to add CSRF token to my file. I think this is obligatory in.net8! (which is a good thing!!! But, it is killing me )
I do not know how should I create this token in my server side.
I found this on chatgpt, but it seems like GetAndValidateRequestTokenAsync does not exist :
    app.MapGet("/GetToken", async (IAntiforgery antiforgery) =>
    {
    var token = await antiforgery.GetAndValidateRequestTokenAsync(HttpContext);
    return token;
    });

how should I create this token and how should I add it to my file stream on client side??

Did you read the error message and its hints?

I used this to add Antiforgery :
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => { });
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAntiforgery();
of course, I read that! But, after this, I do not know how should I even create such token!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-in-aspnet-core

neither postman or your server would have the anti-forgery value.  That will tie the session to the form, before the POST is made.  (You receive this value on the GET... then need to send it along with the POSTed form)  Once you create a new HTTPClient, you have a new session.

If you want to generate CSRF token inside the minial-api ,I suggest you could follow below example:
1.Add Antiforgery service and enable it inside the program.cs:
...
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAntiforgery();
...

2.Add token generate api:
app.MapGet("/gettoken", (HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery) =>
{
    var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    return Results.Content(token.RequestToken );
});

Request header:

Postman body:



You also need set the anti cookie when requesting the gettoken method. You need set it by using the httpclient handler.
Codes like below:
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
// Set the cookie
handler.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(@"https://localhost:7214/"), new Cookie(".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.kCPjFYuL7Oo", "CfDJ8DjJ1xxxxxxx6wbSE"));

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // Set the request URI
    string requestUri = "https://localhost:7214/uploadexlsx";
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.png";
 
 
    using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
 
        using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
        {
        form.Add(fileContent,"file", Path.GetFileName(filepath));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "CxxxxxxLfWc");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form);
        
            // Check response
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

    }



Thanks for your answer. I passed through this part. I created the token and then I successfully transferred an excel file through post command in Postman.
However, I failed sending a file through post command in C#. I added the same headers for my request in C#, but it doesn't work.

how you add the header?

multipartFormDataContent.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", "...")
I shared the client code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446392/post-command-not-working-in-c-sharp-app-but-ok-with-postman

it also need set the anti cookie when requesting the gettoken method. You need set it by using the httpclient handler.

You could check my updated codes.

Besides, if your web api no need for the CSRF you could directly disable it by using the .DisableAntiforgery() method, since if your web api need be called from other host.

It seems like it is obligatory in .net8.

Yes, so if you don't want to use it, you could add DisableAntiforgery to disable CSRF token verify to avoid this, since there is no need for a API need CSRF checking.Like this  app.MapGet().DisableAntiforgery().
